# Clojure.contrib.sql: How do I retrieve the results of a select statement into a vector that can be accessed anytime?

Tags: sql, clojure

For example, in this query:

```
(Clojure.contrib.sql/with-query-results rows ["SELECT count(*) from tableName"] (doseq [record rows] (println (vals record))))
```

It seems that record and rows don't exist outside this scope but I want it to exist anytime for me access.

Update:
I tried the following lines of code

```
(def asdf [])
(sql/with-connection db

(sql/with-query-results rows ["SELECT * FROM tableName"] (doseq [record rows] (def asdf (conj asdf record)))))

(println asdf)
```

Why does the print statement of asdf above return empty when I added the rows to it in the sql statement?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to lack a basic understanding of Clojure's underlying principles, in particular immutable data structures. Your `conj` call doesn't modify the var `asdf` -- a var is not a variable. You could do something like the following (untested)

```
(def asdf 
    (sql/with-connection db
         (doall (sql/with-query-results rows ["SELECT * FROM tableName"]))))
```

to store the result directly as the value of `asdf`, but this is probably not really what you want. Get familiar with [Clojure's take on functional programming](http://clojure.org/functional_programming) instead.